# Telegram echo bot for channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have the following telegram bot written in `Python (3.x)`:

```
import telebot
import subprocess
from telebot import types
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.environ['BOT_API_TOKEN'])
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def save(messages):
    for m in messages:
        if "keyword" in m.text:
            f = open("channel", "a")
            f.write(m.text +  "\n")
            f.close()
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Saved!")

bot.set_update_listener(save)
bot.polling()
```

The idea is to store in the file `channel` the messages that contain the word `keyword`. This bot works perfectly if I talk to him, but if I add the bot to a channel, it doesn't work. The bot has disable the privacy mode and enable the joingroups option.

I have another bot that do the same but with different code:
    import logging
    import os
    from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

```
updater = Updater(token=os.environ['BOT_API_TOKEN'])
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
def save(bot, update):
    print(update.message.text)
    if "keyword" in update.message.text:
        f = open("channel", "a")
        f.write(update.message.text +  "\n")
        f.close()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Saved!")

save_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, save)
dispatcher.add_handler(save_handler)
updater.start_polling()
```

I don't mind in which version can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle channel messages, you need to parse `channel_post` field instead of `message` field.

You can lockup [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) section of official document for more details.

Comment: This works, thanks! Do you know how to send a message to a channel? `bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.update_id, text="Saved!")` doesn't work for me. (My bot is admin of the channel)

Comment: @n23, don't abuse. This is not a comment, is a new question. Check this one as solution and post a new one.